# Draw curved arrow between two points using Quartz Core in iPhone

Tags: iphone, line, quartz-graphics

I want to draw a curved line with arrow between two points using the Quartz Core framework in an iPhone Application. How to do that or any what classes are available to do that ?

Comment: Use either the Cocoa Touch [UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or if you do prefer CoreGraphics/Quartz you can also use [CGPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html). See [Drawing Shapes Using Bezier Paths](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html) or the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the co-ordinates as you want

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    //DRAW CURVE
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100, 100);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 100,200, 300,200, 100);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    //DRAW LINE
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};

    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 300, 400);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGColorRelease(color);

}
```

Comment: Please at least link to the sources where you've copied&pasted your answer from. In this case, that's [An iPhone Graphics Drawing Tutorial using Quartz 2D](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D) which is really useful for the poster.

Comment: the code i have given has been taken from the link you have given

Comment: I know, but you should have said so yourself ! First, simply copy&pasting without revealing the source is rude (and sometimes it's even illegal, but not in this case). Second, the link provides a lot more valuable information.

Comment: Naimy: That doesn't make sense.